# Auto complete a statement in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

Is there a way to auto complete a statement in eclipse? If I type

```
if (condition)
```

it should, after pressing some key, become

```
if (condition) {
    // putting cursor here
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just continue to type the `{` and enter, and the closing bracket will be completed automatically without any special command:

```
if (  condition) { /* cursor here , enter */


if (  condition) { 
  /* cursor here */
}
```

There is also autocompletion (Crtl-Space), which can do the following

```
if /* cursor here , Ctrl-Space */
```

becomes

```
if ( /* cursor here */ condition) {

}
```

or

```
if ( /* cursor here */ condition) {

} else {

}
```

Answer (score 3):

This kind of thing cannot be autocompleted the conventional way, since you're not adding to a class or variable name. However, this should be possible using eclipse templates (Window->Preferences->Java->Editor->Templates)

```
if (${condition:var(boolean)}) {
 ${cursor}
}
```

You can then access the template by typing its name (most likely just 'if') and pressing Ctrl-space

Comment: What does `${condition:var(boolean)}` mean?

Comment: @fastcodejava Eclipse will allow you to choose from any `boolean` variable in scope to insert into the `if` statement.

Comment: Well I don't have direct direct to use, may I want to call a method and check if it is equals to something.

Answer (score 2):

**Ctrl + Space** is default for code assist.
For more customization you need templates.

Answer (score 1):

Try `Ctrl-Space`

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl + Space is used to auto complete words, variable names, classes etc,
if you want eclipse to complete your if statement, do the following:
 - write your if condition along with the first bracket

```
if(condition){
```

- hit enter, then eclipse will do its job.